# unable to load ggstatsplot library

Tags: r, ggplot2

I discovered the ggstatsplot  library and it looks like an amazing tool. Unfortunately, I can't get it to run. Any thoughts or suggestions? I'm running R version 3.6.3 and R Studio version 1.3.1093

```
# > library(ggstatsplot)
# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggstatsplot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
#  there is no package called ‘Rmpfr’
```

Comment: Have you installed the Rmpfr library? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html

Comment: Hah. Looks like I oughta learn to read the error codes. Looks like that got it to run and with that ggstatplot loaded properly. Now let's see if I can get some neat stats only my plots.

Comment: It's all good.  Provided the same info as an answer so you mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html) library (per comment).